# Grouping Regex Groups

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping

I am trying to group regex groups together.  Here is an example of what I mean:

```
var string = 'This is a test string This is a test string';
var regex = /(This)(.+)(string)/g;
var ar = regex.exec(string);
/* output is: 
'This is a test string This is a test string'
'This'
'is a test string This is a test'
'string' */
```

What I want is a way to group that together so the output is instead:

```
/* 'This is a test string This is a test string'
'This is a test string'
'This is a test string' */
```

How can I find all instance of my regex?

Comment: `/((This[\W\w]+?string))/g`, but do you need to use `exec()` ?

Comment: @dandavis What I really want to do is replace certain parts of the string (This) and (string) and leave everything else between them intact.  I dont have control over the string since it is provided to me.  It will have an undetermined quantity of 'This is a test string' and I need to make the same replacements over and over again.  I tried to use replace and use a global flag for this but I did not get the results i was looking for.

Comment: something like `'This is a test string This is a test string'.replace(/((This)([\W\w]+?)(string))/g, function(a,b,c,d,e){ return c.toUpperCase()+ d + e.toUpperCase();})` ?

Comment: @dandavis Could you explain what the parameters in the function are doing?

Comment: @ZDROM can you provide more sample inputs and outputs? We need to figure out the rules of the regex.